# Is $(\frac{4p_2}{p_1})^2$ equivalent to $(\frac{p_1}{4p_2})^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

I was solving a hicksian demand function for my microeconomics class. I seem to have forgotten basic algebra. The answer in my textbook is $(\frac{4p_2}{p_1})^2$. The answer I have arrived at is $(\frac{p_1}{4p_2})^2$. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Those two values are reciprocal, like $\frac 23$ and $\frac 32$.

Comment: @lulu thank you so much, I've found my mistake

Comment: No they are not, $(\frac{4p_2}{p_1})^2$ and $(\frac{p_1}{4p_2})^2$ are reciprocals of each other. It's like $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{b}{a}$. So they are different. I believe there is an error in your calculation. You can put them here so that we may help you.